# Video thumbnail in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list combined of video and image,
I  want to show video thumbnail in list if it's video.
Right now i have shown only icon of video player if it's video
can we show thumbnail ..?

[![The list view][1]][1]

Below is the code

```
    children: [
                        if (post.photo != null)
                          AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 156 / 110,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                AppTheme.mediumBorderRadius,
                              ),
                              child: CustomExtendedImage(
                                url: post.photo!,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (post.video != null)
                          // Get Video Thumbnail somehow
                          const AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 156 / 110,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                FlatIcons.video_camera,
                                size: 100,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use package [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) like this

```
 Future<File> _generateThumbnail() async {
    final String _path = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
      video: 'video_url',
      thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, /// path_provider
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
      maxHeight: 50,
      quality: 50,
    );
    return File(_path);
  }
```